# How to solve "String or binary data would be truncated." TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am experimenting with a store procedure and I get the following error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

I am trying to add user info to a table and I want to hash the password. I found this [guide](http://sqlity.net/en/2460/sql-password-hash/) and am trying to make it work

The code:

```
DECLARE @FirstName nvarchar(20) = 'Name'
DECLARE @LastName nvarchar(20) = 'LastName'
DECLARE @Email nvarchar(50) = 'Name.LastName@hot'
DECLARE @UserPassword nvarchar(12) = 'thepass'


DECLARE @Hash VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @Salt VARBINARY(4) = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)
DECLARE @UserName nvarchar(4)

SET @UserName = SUBSTRING(@FirstName, 1, 2) + SUBSTRING(@LastName, 1, 2) 



SET @Hash = 0x200 + @Salt + HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CAST(@UserPassword AS varbinary(MAX)) + @Salt)

INSERT INTO USERS(Email,UserName,UserPassword,firstName,lastName) VALUES(@Email, @UserName, @Hash, @FirstName, @LastName)
```

Table looks like:

[image]

After searching the web i got info that the size of the hash might be to big for the column but i checked and this is the result of the data:

> 0x0200511C118E7D3BF6F346BCE8F422B6832FDDC0A93A6C4533D79CC8776365E5D591750ADBC0587763494E7152DC68388B583F71182CA4AB6810ECD645381A7933B0785ACA8B

This is 142 characters and is below the 500 maximum.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the size of `lastName(nvarchar(30),null)` in table design

Comment: I'd also change the Userpassword to VARBINARY(MAX) seeing as that is what you want to put in there..

Comment: Red herring, has nothing to do with the hash. You're trying to put the string `'LastName'`, which is 8 characters, into the column `lastName`, which is set to `nvarchar(1)`. You can't fit 8 characters into a column that has a max of 1 character.

Comment: This is the part where I say thank you and turn of my pc for today and try to forget the fact that I actually wasted 2 hours on this. the problem was as you said in the LastName column. I changed the UserPassword column to test if it would work but i changed the Lastname varchar to 30 and changed back the userpassword to varbinary(max) and it worked. Thank you

Comment: also why not use a prebuild user management store?  Rolling your own you'll likely make mistakes, or just not have the featureset that a prebuilt one will

Comment: You should flag the question as answered

Comment: @cameront The question got its answer in a comment. How can i flag the question as answered?